# fading out items in and out in greensock LinePath2D

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

this is the sample code provided in the LinePath2D class

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.motionPaths.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

//create a LinePath2D with 5 Points
var path:LinePath2D = new LinePath2D([new Point(0, 0), 
                                      new Point(100, 100), 
                                      new Point(350, 150),
                                      new Point(50, 200),
                                      new Point(550, 400)]);

//add it to the display list so we can see it (you can skip this if you prefer)
addChild(path);

//create an array containing 30 blue squares
var boxes:Array = [];
for (var i:int = 0; i &lt; 30; i++) {
    boxes.push(createSquare(10, 0x0000FF));
}

//distribute the blue squares evenly across the entire path and set them to autoRotate
path.distribute(boxes, 0, 1, true);

//put a red square exactly halfway through the 2nd segment
path.addFollower(createSquare(10, 0xFF0000), path.getSegmentProgress(2, 0.5));

//tween all of the squares through the path once (wrapping when they reach the end)
TweenMax.to(path, 20, {progress:1});

//while the squares are animating through the path, tween the path's position and rotation too!
TweenMax.to(path, 3, {rotation:180, x:550, y:400, ease:Back.easeOut, delay:3});

//method for creating squares
function createSquare(size:Number, color:uint=0xFF0000):Shape {
    var s:Shape = new Shape();
    s.graphics.beginFill(color, 1);
    s.graphics.drawRect(-size / 2, -size / 2, size, size);
    s.graphics.endFill();
    this.addChild(s);
    return s;
}
```

what would be the simplest way of fading the elements in and out?

should I add a tween to each of the items, or should i hook into the update listener?

Comment: either. I'd do an update listener as it's likely slightly more efficient.

Comment: That's the direction I'm trying, it's a bit more difficult, because it requires changing/extending the LinePath2D class, to give access to some of the protected properties. It looks more complicated than I thought.

Comment: It's unclear to me though what you actually want to do.  Do you want your squares to fade in/out individually when they reach the ends of your path? or just all at the same time when the tween starts and ends?  It would be good to update your question to make that clearer

Comment: turns out that the property i did need (followers) was already exposed

Comment: I did find a small *bug* in the class though, the first and last object overlap (because progress of 0 and 1 are the same) last object should not be added or the position adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this

```
        TweenMax.to(path, $speedNorm, { progress:1, ease:Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1, onUpdate:function():void
            {
                for (var j:int = 0; j < path.followers.length; j++) 
                {
                    var $follower:PathFollower = path.followers[j];
                    if ($follower.progress < 1/$numPoints) {
                        $follower.target.alpha = $follower.progress * $numPoints;
                    }
                    else if ($follower.progress > 1-1/$numPoints) {
                        $follower.target.alpha = (1-$follower.progress) * $numPoints;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

where $numpoints would be 30 based on the example